# Route to new base page

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

In angular I have defined my routes like this:

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'pages/main.html', controller: 'MainController'});
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'pages/login.html', controller: 'AccountController'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

So my web site loads the `pages/main.html` page inside my `index.html`. When I goto `#/login` then my `pages/login.html` inside `index.html`.

But I actually don't want to load `page/login.html` inside `index.html`. I want my login page to have its own layout.

So is there a way to load `login.html` in such a way so that it's not included inside `index.html` as a partial, but so that it can have it's own base layout?

Comment: One way would be not use routing at all, that way each page could have it's own layout.

Comment: So, you actually want the ng-view directive to be on the <body> of index.html, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could create new html page for login page so it could use bage template 
for eg:
base-template.html

```
<html>
<head>Your scripts</head>
<body ng-app="yourmodule">
<ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>

create login.html

<div>
First Name:<input type="text"/>
Last Name:<input type="password"/>
</div>

var app = angular.module("Your module",[ngroute]);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:'login.html',
            controller:'your controller'
        });
app.controller("Your controller",function($scope){
//your logic
});
```

Hope it helps you